# How to setup a maven project in Intellij IDEA 12

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have problem importing a maven project which was created by Netbeans into the IDEA 12. The dependency artifacts writen in the pom doesn't work. It told me that "cannot resolve symbol 'springframework'" on "import org.springframework.xxx;". When I runs it, it says that org.springframework.xxx doesn't exist.
Here is the pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>cn.edu.seu.cose.jellyjolly</groupId>
<artifactId>jellyjolly-openshift-dist</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Jelly Jolly Openshift Distribution</name>
<organization>
    <name>College of Software Engineering, Southeast University</name>
    <url>http://cose.seu.edu.cn/</url>
</organization>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-restlet</id>
        <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <netbeans.hint.license>gpl30</netbeans.hint.license>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.Final-redhat-1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.rome</groupId>
        <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when
                    invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app
                    will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps'
                    folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>jellyjolly</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Should be straightforward and independent of Netbeans. Maybe check the general Maven settings (File -> Settings -Maven) and try reimporting the project (Right click project -> Maven -> Reimport). 
Also check for some "errors" in your pom.xml. Maybe there is an "error" which netbeans ignored, but IDEA not.

Comment: Actually there may be an error in the pom file. The hint is "Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the meta data file for artifact 'javax.activation:activation:jar': Unable to parse version '[0.9.1.2, 0.9.1.2-redhat-1]' fo dependency 'c3p0:c3p0:jar': Range defies version ordering: [0.9.1.2,0.9.1.2-redhat-1] for project unknown: jboos-dependency-management-build ... from the specified remote repositories: central, eap, ... Path to dependency xxx:xxx:war ...". Does it mean that some artifacts can not be retrieved from the repositories that are listed?

Comment: Very strange behaviour. Please recheck the Mavne version IDEA uses, maybe you could try to override the internal version with your external.

Comment: Also, better use specific versions instead of ranges, so 0.9.1.2 instead of [0.9.1.2, 0.9.1.2-redhat-1] and so on.

Comment: Does it help if you enable **Maven 3** in IDEA Maven settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the project runs on the command line (`mvn clean install`) the chance is like 100% it will work in IntelliJ 12 too :-)

After File -> Project Import -> From external Maven Model you should see the modules.

What I would check in the IntelliJ settings is the location of the maven home directory (File -> Settings -> Maven) and the settings.xml files it reads (or does not read).

The `mvn install` within the IDE should not differ from what happens on the command line. If it does it would compare `mvn help:effective-settings` output from the command line and from IntelliJ (maybe also from Netbeans).

If you just dont see all modules right click on the parent-pom.xml and choose maven -> reimport. To resolve the dependencies you have to execute an install once. It does not automatically resolve dependencies in all cases.

Comment: Though there is a error hint on the pom file saying that "Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the meta data file for artifact 'javax.activation:activation:jar': Unable to parse version '[0.9.1.2, 0.9.1.2-redhat-1]' fo dependency 'c3p0:c3p0:jar' ... Path to dependency xxx:xxx:war ...", mvn clean install process finished successfully with exit code 0. I was wondering whether the artifacts were downloaded from the remote mvn repositories. It seems that the artifacts cannot be found on these repositories.

Comment: well they may be broken. So I would delete the local repository and retry. Also use help:effective-pom and help:effective-settings to check if maven central is in you repository list.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The artifacts from the local repository are broken as you said. The dependency of spring framework and others is resolved, but the dependency of artifacts that do not serve on the central repository remains unsolved. Should non-central repositories be declared in not only pom.xml but settings.xml as well?

Comment: additional repos you use for multiple projects should be put into settings.xml. In most cases it is better to not add repositories into pom.xml as this relates to a project. Since repositories are infrastructure the settings.xml is the better place. Once you use a maven proxy you only need to update the settings.xml and not the pom.xml files. You have to add them only in settings.xml or in pom.xml - not in both locations.

Comment: I just remove the dependency of jboss-javaee-6.0 and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

When the `pom.xml` file is available in your project, you can generate the files needed by IntelliJ idea project by running this command:

`mvn idea:idea`

Check out more options and details here:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem,
you can simply Right+Click on the code and go Maven->Reimport and it should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I used `mvn -U idea:idea` to generate the IntelliJ specific files with dependencies downloaded.